# Dynamically delete rows from parent table after deleting rows from multiple child table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a script that will return the parent and child table details with respective key columns and the order in which the table's row should be deleted.
Below is the details return by the script:

```
| Child_table| Child_column| Parent_Table| Parent_Column| Delete_Order|
|:-----------|:------------| ------------| -------------|-------------|
| Child1     | Child1_ID   | Child2      | Child2_Id    |  2          |
| Child2     | Child2_ID1  | Parent1     | Parent_ID    |  1          |
| Child3     | Child3_ID   | Parent1     | Parent_ID    |  1          |
| Parent1    | Parent_ID   |             |              |  0          |
```

In the above table, **`Child1`** is a child table of **`Child2`** and **`Child2`** and **`Child3`** are child tables of **`Parent1`**. Now I need to delete data from the child to parent table in descending order given in the `Delete_Order` column.

I need help to write a dynamic query that will join these tables and
delete the data from the Child and Parent table based on primary key data
from the parent table.

Comment: "I need help" is not a question. You obviously know that this involves dynamic sql, so I suggest you start with a cursor running over the table in the proper order. However I suspect there is something missing here. Are you intending to delete ALL ROWS from these tables?

Comment: What have you tried? Please, paste your code and we will help you with it. And  choose well your tags, please, you have selected "mysql" and also "sql-server"... which one is the true one?

Comment: A refererence (FK) column info is missing.

Comment: @SMor Yes I am using dynamic query, and instead of using cursor I am trying for while loop. And Yes I am deleting all the rows.

Comment: @Carlos I am trying but not sure how to dynamically join these multiple tables. It is for sql-server, hence I removed my-sql. Thank You

Comment: @Serg Child_col and Parent_col are FK reference for child and parent table.

Comment: _I am trying for while loop_ Nope - that is no, ZERO, improvement over a cursor. If you need a cursor, then just use one. Any other looping construct is just a more error-prone alternative. And I repeat - you have to start with a loop somewhere and that is the easy part of your solution. So write it, verify that it works correctly, and then post it as a starting point for your discussion. Your question will be closed without more detail.

Comment: Try using a recursive cte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create DELETE statements using recursive CTE. Statements must be run in the `do desc` order. Replace '=1' with a proper value.

```
with cte as (
    select cast('delete' + x.childAlias + ' from ' + Child_table + x.childAlias +
           case when Parent_Column is null then ' where ' + Child_column + ' = 1;' else '' end as nvarchar(max))  sql,
        x.childAlias, Child_column, 
        Parent_Table, Parent_Column, 
        Delete_Order do
    from tbl
    cross apply (select ' t' + cast(tbl.Delete_Order as varchar(3))) x(childAlias)
    
    union all
    
    select cte.sql + ' join ' + tbl.Child_table + x.childAlias + 
           ' on' + cte.childAlias+ '.' + cte.Child_column + ' =' + x.childAlias + '.'+ cte.Parent_Column +
           case when tbl.Parent_Column is null then ' where' + x.childAlias + '.' + tbl.Child_column + ' = 1;' else '' end  sql,
        x.childAlias, tbl.Child_column,
        tbl.Parent_Table, tbl.Parent_Column,
        do  
    from cte
    join tbl on cte.Parent_Table = tbl.Child_table
    cross apply (select ' t' + cast(tbl.Delete_Order as varchar(3))) x(childAlias)
 ) 
 select sql, do
 from cte
 where sql like '%where%'
 order by do desc
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0988c0fb77348fe5d31c58c9b3defbc3)

Comment: Question is the first CTE will give you the parent information as the condition given is parent_column is null and what value is likely to be in "=1" ? Trying to understand the logic here.

Comment: Replace '1' with the `Parent_ID` value of the row in the  `Parent1`  table which is to be deleted with all its desendants.

Comment: Is the query written here is in correct format ?  `cast('delete' + x.childAlias + ' from ' + Child_table + x.childAlias + case when Parent_Column is null then ' where ' + Child_column + ' = 1;' else '' end as nvarchar(max))  sql,
 x.childAlias, Child_column, Parent_Table, Parent_Column, Delete_Order do
 from tbl
cross apply (select ' t' + cast(tbl.Delete_Order as varchar(3))) x(childAlias)` . This query have case after from table name and have x.ChildAlias in middle of no where. Could you please explain this in detail  ?

Comment: @SqlProgrammer, added the fiddle. You can try in step by step to see what's happenning.

Comment: did some tweak and it's working. Thank You